# Undefined is not an object while filtering a Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, firebase, native

I'm trying to filter some data in react native, but when the data come from a JS file it works when they come from a firebase DB it says "undefined is not an object (evaluating `MeasuresList.filter`)"

this is the code

```
<FlatList style={styles.flatList}
          data = {ExercisesList.filter(item => item.muscle === "shoulders")}}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => 
                     {item.name}
                        }
                    />
```

If I delete the filter part and I get into the screen I can see the flatlist with all the exercises, if then I add the filter part and I save I can see the elements filtered and it works. The problem is that I can't get into this page when I have the filter code added, even if it seems to work, why is "`MeasuresList.filter`" undefined just before I get into the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
Array.isArray(MeasuresList) && MeasuresList?.filter
```

You should also set the default value of `MeasuresList` as `[]`

Comment: @AymanNasreddin you should accept this answer then

Answer (score 1):

[Undefined is not an object] means, MeasuresList is undefined. In this case, [ExercisesList.filter] is the same as the [undefined.filter].

So you should check if the MeasuresList is undefined or defined value.

```
{ExercisesList? ExercisesList.filter(item => item.muscle === "shoulders") : []}
```

Please let me know if it works for you or not.
Thanks.

Comment: This worked too, but you added a "}" after shoulders that I deleted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, yes. It was my fault. thanks a lot. :D